# Passing Children Styling Down to a Styled Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I am making a generalized version of a styled component to replace duplicated code in my codebase. The component looks something like this:

```
const CustomDiv = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  b {
     padding-right:5px
   }
`;

const DivWrapper = ({style, children}) => {
  return (
    <CustomDiv style={style}>
      {children}
    </CustomDiv>
  );
};
```

I want to be use this "DivWrapper" in other places of the code base but be able to change the b padding in other places when using it. I tried extending it like this:

```
const SuperCustomDiv = styled(CustomDiv)`
  b {
    padding-right:10px
  }
`;
```

I am using the styled components library for React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using css props and passing props from the styled-component to the CSS. So, we create styled CSS with some property, then this style place to both styled components. With props, we will pass the value to main style.

```js
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const PaddingStyle = (value) => css`
  padding-right: ${value}px;
`;

export const SuperCustomDiv = styled.b`
  ${PaddingStyle((props) => props.padding)}
`;

export const CustomDiv = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  b {
    ${PaddingStyle((props) => props.padding)}
  }
`;

export const DivWrapper = ({ padding = 50, children }) => {
  return (
    <CustomDiv as="div" padding={padding}>
      <b>Name:</b> {children}
    </CustomDiv>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DivWrapper>John Doe</DivWrapper>
      <SuperCustomDiv padding={30}>Super</SuperCustomDiv>
      <span>John Smith</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]